# Change nested array values in multiple fields using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Trying to loop thru array (query results of mysql db table), find four different fields and add a prefix.

I have four image versions -- full size, med, small, thumb -- as table fields (mysql). The values are file names. I want to prefix https://... to each so that I have the full address for each image.

My query returns an associative array (`$myArray`). The foreach loop looks for a `$key` match to the image field, and if true displays the current value, then adds the prefix, then displays the new value. What displays as the "*New value*" includes the prefix, so that part of the code is working as expected.

However, when I display `$myArray` afterward, the "*changed*" values are not changed. They are only the original file names without the prefix.

I am unable to figure out how to apply the new value to the array.

Here's my code:

```
$prefix = 'example.com/assets/images/';

foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {

  if ($key == 'image_full_size') {
     echo 'Current value: ' . $value['image_full_size'] . '<br>';
     $value['image_full_size'] = $prefix . $value['image_full_size'];
     echo 'New value: ' . $value['image_full_size'] . '<br>';
  }

  if ($key == 'image_med') {
     echo 'Current value: ' . $value['image_med'] . '<br>';
     $value['image_med'] = $prefix . $value['image_med'];
     echo 'New value: ' . $value['image_med']. '<br>';
  }

  if ($key == 'image_small') {
     echo 'Current value: ' . $value['image_small'] . '<br>';
     $value['image_small'] = $prefix . $value['image_small'];
     echo 'New value: ' . $value['image_small']. '<br>';
  }

  if ($key == 'image_thumb') {
     echo 'Current value: ' . $value['image_thumb'] . '<br>';
     $value['image_thumb'] = $prefix . $value['image_thumb'];
     echo 'New value: ' . $value['image_thumb']. '<br>';
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help in finding my error(s).

First two records from array:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [id] => 1
           [laser_series] => GTO FLX
           [laser_model] => GTO/FLX01
           [laser_color] => red
           [price] => 118.75
           [image_full_size] => example.com/assets/images/laser-pistol/gto-flx01_black_red_1080x720.png
           [image_med] => example.com/assets/images/laser-pistol/gto-flx01_red_med.png
           [image_small] => example.com/assets/images/laser-pistol/gto-flx01_red_small.png
           [image_thumb] => example.com/assets/images/laser-pistol/gto-flx01_red_thumb.png
           [ad_blurb] => Custom-designed to fit this brand and model. The GTO/FLX series laser is the most technologically-advanced laser sight available for this popular pistol.
           [feature01] => Grip-Touch Activation by using FLX
           [feature02] => Side-Touch Activation without FLX
           [feature03] => Ultra-bright 635nm red laser
           [special_message] => 
           [mfr_name] => Kel-Tec
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [id] => 3
           [laser_series] => GTO FLX
           [laser_model] => GTO/FLX02
           [laser_color] => red
           [price] => 118.75
           [image_full_size] => gto-flx02_black_red_1080x720.png
           [image_med] => gto-flx02_red_med.png
           [image_small] => gto-flx02_red_small.png
           [image_thumb] => gto-flx02_red_thumb.png
           [ad_blurb] => Custom-designed to fit this brand and model. The GTO/FLX series laser is the most technologically-advanced laser sight available for this popular pistol.
           [feature01] => Grip-Touch Activation by using FLX
           [feature02] => Side-Touch Activation without FLX
           [feature03] => Ultra-bright 635nm red laser
           [special_message] => 
           [mfr_name] => Kel-Tec
       )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The foreach loop looks for a $key match to the image field, and if
> true displays the current value, then adds the prefix, then displays
> the new value. What displays as the "New value" includes the prefix,
> so that part of the code is working as expected.

No - It's not working as expected. It just looks like that.

Your row keys are numeric. But you are comparing them to strings like that: `$key == 'image_full_size'`. In this case PHP seems to cast the string to a number and that would be `0`. So the condition is only true, if the `$key` is `0`. You can see that behaviour here: http://rextester.com/XDORW8182

This is the reason why it only works for the first row where the key is `0`.

So your attempt is wrong. And a working solution is not that complicated:

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $row) {
    $myArray[$key]['image_full_size'] = $prefix . $row['image_full_size'];
    $myArray[$key]['image_med']       = $prefix . $row['image_med'];
    $myArray[$key]['image_small']     = $prefix . $row['image_small'];
    $myArray[$key]['image_thumb']     = $prefix . $row['image_thumb'];
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/JEA91624

#### Original answer:

In

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
     $value['image_full_size'] = $prefix . $value['image_full_size'];
}
```

`$value` is a (local) copy of `$myArray[$key]` and you are changing that copy. If you want to change the original row in `$myArray` you should acces that row by the `$key`:

```
$myArray[$key]['image_full_size'] = $prefix . $value['image_full_size'];
```

Another way would be to access the row by *reference* with

```
foreach($myArray as $key => &$value) {...}
```

But that might have some unwanted side effects, so you better avoid that.

Comment: Thanks Paul! The new values display in $myArray, but only for the first record. Apparently my foreach loop isn't looping. Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: @JimB814 Please post an example of `$myArray` (in the question). Use `var_export($myArray)`. After looking at your code closer, I don't think I understand how the array is structured.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Info added.

Comment: Paul, do you have everything from me that you need?

Comment: @JimB814 Did you read the update? You need to remove the `if` conditions.

Comment: Missed that. I'll check it out!

Comment: Thanks Paul. I applied your solution in rextester, and it works as expected. Apparently, the if statement was causing a problem. Seeing the working solution makes clear that the if statement is unnecessary. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it!